# Can I debug django to display which template it is rendering?

Tags: python, django, templates

I use django for a large project that is new for me and has many templates. Now I was asked to edit a template that I can display in the browser but I don't know where the template is. Is there a way to make django write out which template it is rendering (and possibly which python classes are used)? Similar to what happens at an error where there is lots of information about what is used.

Comment: You can start from urls.py and find the views and corresponding template .. have fun ...

Comment: @RajaSimon Thanks. There are 17 files named urls.py ... It's not easy to know coming to a new project like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes definitely, you can use [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) for this !